File Not found error in intellij idea but the program throws no error when I compile and run it on terminal
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("note.txt")){
            int letters = fr.read();
            while(fr.ready()) {
                System.out.println((char)letters);
                letters = fr.read();
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

when I run from Intellij idea:
I got:

note.txt (No such file or directory)

but I compiled it and ran it on the terminal, the program reads from the file and prints it.
I don't understand why this isn't working on IntelliJ-idea

Did you set the working directory correctly in your run configuration? I suspect you didn't do that.

you expect a runtime error to be thrown at compile time? Why? Did you use the complete path? Working within the context of an IDE has an impact on that

Side note: copying a file char by char is very inefficient, especially when not compensating with a BufferedReader. You can copy the entire file using something like try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("note.txt")) { fr.transferTo(System.console().writer()); System.console().writer().flush(); }

Or even System.out.println(Files.readString(Path.of("note.txt")));

This is happening because "note.txt" does not mean “search every folder on my computer for a file named note.txt.”  It means “a file named note.txt in the current working directory of the Java process.”  This is not just a Java issue;  every single program on every operating system works this way.

Please check the current working directory value in the run configuration dialog: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2024.1/run-debug-configuration-java-application.html#required
Specify the working directory to be used for running the application. This directory is the starting point for all relative input and output paths. By default, the working directory is the project root.
If you test it under IDEA, the note.txt should be put under your project's root, eg:
note.txt
/src/com/xx/MyTest.java
